# How do I check if user input is in data file C# and display correct message?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the data file named "ChargeAccounts.txt". I need to search this data file for a users account number entered in the textbox txtAccount.

---

```
 5658845
 4520125
 7895122
 8777541
 8451277
 1302850
 8080152
 4562555
 5552012
 5050552
 7825877
 1250255
 1005231
 6545231
 3852085
 7576651
 7881200
 4581002
```

---

I need to accomplish this using this array.

```
    const int SIZE = 18;
    string[] acct = new string[SIZE];
```

---

This is the code I have and it will only display "Account is invalid." even when I enter a account number from the data file.

```
    private void FindAccountNumber()
    {
       System.IO.StreamReader file =
       new System.IO.StreamReader("ChargeAccounts.txt");

        acct = File.ReadAllLines("ChargeAccounts.txt");


        for (int i = 0; i < acct.Length; i++)
        {

            if (txtAccount.Text.Contains(acct[i]))
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Account is valid";
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Account is invalid.";
            }
        }

      file.Close();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over all elements and updating `lblMessage.Text` for every iteration. So, you can get valid state only if `txtAccount.Text` contains last number in the file. You should break the `for` statement when valid number found, it will look like this

```
string message = "Account is invalid.";
for (int i = 0; i < acct.Length; i++)
{
    if (txtAccount.Text.Contains(acct[i]))
    {
        message = "Account is valid";
        break;
    }
}
lblMessage.Text = message;
```